# Increasing understanding of Python 3 function calls and variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following Python script I have a couple of questions to check my understanding. Any help would be much appreciated in responding to points 1 and 2 below.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())

current_file = open(input_file)

print("First let's print the whole file:\n")

print_all(current_file)

print("Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.")

rewind(current_file)

print("Let's print three lines:")

current_line = 1

print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1 

print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1

print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

1) Each time the `print_a_line` function is run, the variable `current_line` is passed to the function. How would I find a way to output what `current_line` is equal to on each function call? I was thinking the function could simply be changed to use the built in function `print()` like so:

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(current_line)
    print(line_count, f.readline())
```

2) I have been asked to 'trace' how the variable `current_line` becomes `line_count` in the 'print_a_line' function. The simplest answer I can think of is that the function is called and the variable `current_line` is passed as an argument to `line_count`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this makes it any clearer, but here goes...

You can't really pass variables to functions in Python, only their values.
(When we say "pass x to f", it means "pass the value of x to f".)

The *value* of `current_line` is passed to `print_a_line` as its first argument.
That argument is called "line_count", and its value is the same as the value that you passed in.

The *variable* `current_line` does not exist from `print_a_line`'s point of view; it's defined in a different *scope* and you can't observe it from that function.